# Custom flags to translate jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, google-translate

Some days ago I found some code for translating a webpage with the googleTranslateElementInit() functions. So here I am, after trying to edit my flag-code into the jQuery I found.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'nl', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
  }
</script>
<script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Flag click handler -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#vlaggetjes img').click(function() {
      var lang = $(this).data('lang');
      var $frame = $('.goog-te-menu-frame:first');
      if (!$frame.size()) {
        alert("Error: Could not find Google translate frame.");
        return false;
      }
      $frame.contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item span.text:contains('+lang+')').get(0).click();
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

Here are the flags I want to click on..

```
<div id="vlaggetjes">
            <img src="img/nl.png" class="vlag" id="nederlands" alt="nl" data-lang="Dutch">
            <img src="img/du.png" class="vlag" id="duits" alt="du" data-lang="German">
            <img src="img/eng.png" class="vlag" id="engels" alt="eng" data-lang="English">
</div>
```

Can someone tell me why it isn't working? And why is the google selector-box still shown in the bottom-left of the page?

I've set my body as the element to be translated like this:

```
<body id="google_translate_element">
```

The Site is in dutch, and needs translationoptions in english and german.

PEVIEW:
http://athena.fhict.nl/users/i304115/Lpf/

Greetings!